# How to make OR condition in Xpath query

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have two different type of html code:

my first code is:

```
<div class="course-general-info hide-for-medium-up">
<!-- TODO: check date format here -->
  <div class="headline"><strong>2014-01-27</strong></div>
  <div class="subline">Course start</div>
  <div class="headline"><strong>2014-04-27</strong></div>
  <div class="subline">Course end</div>
<div class="headline">Basis</div>
<div class="subline">Level</div>
</div>
```

my second code is:

```
<div class="course-general-info hide-for-medium-up">
  <div class="headline">Available Soon</div>
  <div class="subline">Course start</div>
<!-- TODO: check date format here -->
<div class="headline">Basis</div>
<div class="subline">Level</div>
</div>
```

i need to fetch the following value in single Xpath query 
    **2014-01-27** or
    Available Soon

my separate xpath queries are:

```
courseDurationDate = courseDetailData.xpath('//div[@class = "headline"]/strong/text()').extract()

CourseDutaionAvailableSoon = courseDetailData.xpath('//div[@class = "headline"]/text()').extract()
```

kindly help to write or condition in Xpath query. thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only one of the 2 `divs` will appear at the same time, this should do it:

```
(//div[@class = "headline"]/strong | 
 //div[@class = "headline" and not(strong)])[1]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

a one-liner

```
div[@class='course-general-info hide-for-medium-up']/div[@class='headline'][1]/descendant::text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following Xpath Query its worked for me:

```
courseDurationDate = courseDetailData.xpath('//div[@class = "course-general-info hide-for-medium-up"]/div[@class = "headline"]/strong/text() | \
                                                 //div[@class = "course-general-info hide-for-medium-up"]/div[@class = "headline" and not (strong)][1]/text()').extract()
```